# returning results of multiple Sequelize queries

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, sequelize.js

my endpoint needs to return the results of multiple sequelize.query() statements that use multiple tables. how do I ensure that all the statements have executed befire building the JSON?

Answer (score 1):

You could chain the queries using `.then()`, but using `Promise.all()` would likely be better, particularly if you have many queries.